# Input Validation, how can i enter unique name

Tags: android, sqlite

I have coded a qr reader system and there are some part that I want to correct.

`ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(BeneficiaryContract.BeneficiaryEntry._ID, beneficiary.getId());
 values.put(BeneficiaryContract.BeneficiaryEntry.COLUMN_BENEFICIARY_NAME, 
 beneficiary.getName());
 values.put(BeneficiaryContract.BeneficiaryEntry.COLUMN_BENEFICIARY_EMAIL, 
 beneficiary.getEmail());
 values.put(BeneficiaryContract.BeneficiaryEntry.COLUMN_BENEFICIARY_DATE, 
 beneficiary.getDate());
 values.put(BeneficiaryContract.BeneficiaryEntry.COLUMN_BENEFICIARY_ADDRESS, 
 beneficiary.getAddress());
 values.put(BeneficiaryContract.BeneficiaryEntry.COLUMN_BENEFICIARY_COUNTRY, 
 beneficiary.getCountry());`

Here is my inserting codes. but I want that not to insert same name. I have to block insertion two same name.

Can you please help me?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to insert unique names into sql. I want to learn how can i do that?

Comment: Make that column unique constraint and while you insert a duplicate value, you'll get an exception catch that perform the desired action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to enforce a unique beneficiary name would be to add a unique constraint to the corresponding column in your table.  Then, any attempts to add a duplicate beneficiary name would fail at the database level, resulting in an exception in Java code, which you could catch and handle appropriately.  Unfortunately, you cannot add unique constraints to tables which already exist, so you would have to recreate your beneficiary table with a unique constraint.  In any case, the following `CREATE TABLE` statement would hopefully give you an idea of how to proceed:

```
CREATE TABLE BeneficiaryContract (
    BENEFICIARY_NAME     VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    BENEFICIARY_EMAIL    VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    BENEFICIARY_DATE     VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    BENEFICIARY_ADDRESS  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    BENEFICIARY_COUNTRY  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT beneficiary_name_unique UNIQUE (BENEFICIARY_NAME)
);
```

Comment: I am tryin' to do it sir. I hope it is done. :) I got the idea i upvoted it.